# SOLR joining 3 streams

Tags: solr

trying to combine data from 3 tables into 1 table, ala relational database join.
Joining 2 SOLR streams works. But how to include a third stream?

btw. This needs to work with millions of rows. Is this a suitable approach? Hopefully all data does not need to be loaded into memory. Goal is to do most processing in solr and less in application.

Part 1 works:

```
innerJoin(
        select(
            search(dbv-database-49461a12-8b70-41f0-b5c4-c9b6c84cb5b0,q=tableId:*elevkarakter AND col1_l:166, fl="col0_l,col1_l,col2_t,col4_t,col3_l", sort="col3_l asc"),
            col1_l as elevar,
            col2_t as Termin,
            col4_t as Karakter,
            col3_l as FagkarakterId_fk),
        select(
            search(dbv-database-49461a12-8b70-41f0-b5c4-c9b6c84cb5b0,q=tableId:*fagkarakter, fl="col0_l,col1_l", sort="col0_l asc"),
            col0_l as FagkarakterId,
            col1_l as FagId),       
        on="FagkarakterId=FagkarakterId_fk"
    )
```

Part 2 works:

```
select(
    search(dbv-database-49461a12-8b70-41f0-b5c4-c9b6c84cb5b0,q=tableId:*fag, fl="col0_l, col5_t", sort="col0_l asc"),
    col0_l as FagId,
    col5_t as fag
)
```

Can I join Part 1 and Part 2 doing something like this?

```
innerJoin(
    select(
        search(dbv-database-49461a12-8b70-41f0-b5c4-c9b6c84cb5b0,q=tableId:*fag, fl="col0_l, col5_t", sort="col0_l asc"),
        col0_l as FagId,
        col5_t as fag),
    innerJoin(
            select(
                search(dbv-database-49461a12-8b70-41f0-b5c4-c9b6c84cb5b0,q=tableId:*elevkarakter AND col1_l:166, fl="col0_l,col1_l,col2_t,col4_t,col3_l", sort="col3_l asc"),
                col1_l as elevar,
                col2_t as Termin,
                col4_t as Karakter,
                col3_l as FagkarakterId),
            select(
                search(dbv-database-49461a12-8b70-41f0-b5c4-c9b6c84cb5b0,q=tableId:*fagkarakter, fl="col0_l,col1_l", sort="col0_l asc"),
                col0_l as FagkarakterId,
                col1_l as FagId),       
            on="FagkarakterId"
    ),
    on="FagId"
)
```

Result so far:

```
"EXCEPTION": "Invalid JoinStream - all incoming stream comparators (sort) must be a superset of this stream's equalitor."
```

Comment: A join needs both sides to be sorted by the same key, so in the join you're returning that's not the case - since it's sorted on `FagkarakterId` and not on `FagId` (for any non-scandinavian speakers: these column names identifies _courses_). Also, if you have to re-sort one of your streams, Solr will have to keep the whole set in memory as far as I know; if you can solve it by just the sequence of documents from the source itself, it'll be far mor efficient. Another solution is to do the merge when you index instead; it'll be easier for generating stats, etc.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you! It works now, when I resort the stream, by wrapping the innerJoin part in a sort( ... ), by="FagId asc". You may want to repost your comment as the answer? The re-sorting/memory may become a showstopper for large datasets, so we may want to solve this at index time, as you mention. But then afraid of duplicating a lot of data. I also needed to add the rows=1000000 to make sure I got enough results. At least in the admin gui. A little scary not to be absolutely sure having the complete result set.

Comment: Duplication is part of the game when talking about document stores - it's part of what makes them effective at what they do, since it allows you to move most of the required calculation and processing from query time to index time instead. Don't attempt to follow regular RDBM normalization when using Solr - instead design a document structure that can efficiently answer the questions you want to have answered (and use streaming expressions etc. to bridge the gap as necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join needs both sides to be sorted by the same key, so in the join you're returning that's not the case - since it's sorted on `FagkarakterId` and not on `FagId`. Think of these streams as being a, well, stream of documents, where each document at the front of the left stream is consumed while checking if the front document in the other stream matches the join condition:

For each document in the left stream, check if the document at the head of `right` matches. Given two streams, left and right:

```
left         right
----         -----
foo          foo
bar          foo
baz          baz

left.pop() -> foo; 

while right.head == foo:
    # pops the next two documents in right

left         right
----         -----
bar          baz
baz          

left.pop -> bar

.. nothing matches in right

left         right
----         -----
baz          baz

left.pop -> baz

while right.head == baz:
    # pops the next document in right
```

You can see how this merge strategy require the two streams to be sorted by the same value that you're joining on.

If you have to re-sort one of your streams, Solr will have to keep the whole set in memory (since it'll have to read the stream until end and then sort the documents) as far as I know. If you can solve it by just the sequence of documents from the source itself, it'll be far more efficient.

Another solution is to do the merge when you index instead; it'll be easier for generating stats, etc.

Comment: Nice! Let's assume Grades has one Course. Then list grades and course name for 1 student. I could solve this by letting an app run 2 queries. Get the grades for a student (say 100 rows). Collect the uniqe foregin keys (say 50). Ask solr to give me all course names with id in [set of foregin keys] (50 rows). Then join quickly in app array. If using streams: Is SOLR also able to look at the on-statement and prefilter the course stream, before sending it? Or will it send every single row each time? We have other tables with millions of rows, but very few rows needs to take part in the actual join

Comment: You pre-filter the stream by knowing what you need ahead of time - it's what you give as `q` to your stream. You only want to retrieve relevant documents here, so if you want to do this for a single student you add an `AND` statement that includes the studentId as well. Your stream expression would be the same otherwise. Only the `search` calls return a stream that will be processed as necessary (using the `/export` endpoint in the back). No queries are sent as part of the join; they are narrow operations that uses the supplied streams for their content.

Comment: This way you can process very large amounts of data without having to keep everything in RAM or perform a join across very large tables. You can assume that the streams represents everything necessary and you can process them row by row and skip the rows that doesn't have any matches. This works very good for typical analytics and bigger data operations. For your example I'm not able to follow it exactly in my head, but no, you won't get source2 prefiltered against values from source1, since the search operations are independent.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly. Streams could be disk intensive, reading more rows that what is strictly needed for table 2, but good on memory. But could run into some issues depending on the need to re-sort for stream 3. And we need to look more into solving this at the data level, using streams/joins more sparingly. In-app join seem to work fine and predictable, actually, but there are many scenarios to account for. This phase is about gathering requirements and find a good design for further development.

Comment: We store RDBMS data for our members in SIARD format. We shall give secure insight into those data. (Central online, But also local & offline for sensitive data). DBPTK open source lets us dump siards into solr, and browse table by table, and thats a good start. But we need meaningful searches and views into the data, across several tables. Either solved query time, or by transforming the data. Many SIARDs lack foregin key definitions. We need to tell the query code (or index engine) what is related. The search and view config must be sharable by e.g. json format, among customers for reuse.

Comment: Putting the SIARDs back into a huge RDBMS cluster could potentially work fine for views. Or many docker containers. But we shall potentially support thousands of databases. Maybe a solr approach may require a less complex infrastructure, and is instantly available. We could also dump data into Graph-database/rdf or other approaches. But dbptk/solr gives us a head start. Feel free to advice :)